# How to traverse all thread_local variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-local-storage

I would like to update a variable which is altered by multiple threads.

I could use a single atomic variable, and atomically increment it, but it is **allegedly** slow.

A proposed solution has been to allocate a thread-local variable, and increment it.

```
thread_local unsigned int _tls_size = 0U;
/* ... */
_tls_size++;
/* ... */
```

This step is ok, but the problem is now to calculate the sum of all `_tls_size` stored across threads.

Any ideas ? I thought about having a `std::vector<unsigned int *>` storing all addresses, but :

- Visual Studio didn't like it and returned errors.
- What happens when a thread detachs ? The corresponding pointer will not be referencing valid memory !

Thank you !

Comment: It depends on the architecture, but given "Visual Studio", TLS is almost _guaranteed_ to be the same speed or slower than an atomic increment. Under the Windows TLS model, every access involves at least two cache-unfriendly additional layers of indirection. In the worst case, it's a W32 API call. An atomic increment takes what, a dozen clocks?

Comment: FWIW, my experience with Windows TLS was very consistent with what  @Damon wrote above.

Comment: Hi,
The thing is that the increment happens very often (it is used to track the size of a hash table), and if I could save a dozen clocks it would be great.
Actually, using thread_local was an idea referenced in this whitepaper, so I decided to implement it : https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t39.2178-6/851557_594511547233607_982257879_n.pdf (slides 39 to 46)